# Tomar dato de un select y guardarlo en base de datos con php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo el siguiente problema: tengo un form y dentro de este un select que lista datos tomados de un query que hace a una db, mi problema es que cuando doy clic al boton cargar, en la bd siempre carga el valor 0 y no el value del dato que elijo.

Este es mi código, este es el form:

```
<?php

include('../inc.php');

$t = mysqli_query($cnx, "SELECT * FROM juegos_mk");
?>
<form action="carga_jugador.php" method ="POST">
<p>version mk:</p>
<select>
        <?php

        while ($v = mysqli_fetch_array($t)) {
            echo "<option value=".$v['id'].">".$v['version_mk']."   </option>";

        };
        ?>
</select><br>
<p>Nombre jugador: </p><input type="text" name="jugador">
<p>Historia: </p><textarea name="historia" id="historia" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<p> imagen: </p><input type="text" name="img"><br><br>
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="1">cargar</button>
</form>
```

y este es el código php que cargaría los datos a la base:

```
<?php

include ('../inc.php');

$juego = $_POST['id'];
$jugador = $_POST['jugador'];
$historia = $_POST['historia'];

echo "<p>".$juego."</p>";
echo "<p>".$jugador."</p>";
//mysqli_query ($cnx, "INSERT INTO `jugadores_mk` (`version_mk`,  `nombre_jugador`, `historia`) VALUES ('$juego', '$jugador', '$historia')");

echo ("se cargo todo");

?>

<hr><br>
<a href="jugadores.php">volver</a>
```

Carga todos los datos menos el del value que siempre carga un 0 y este es el error que me tira:

> Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyects\mk\includes\carga_jugador.php on line 5

Comment: Aquí `$_POST['id']` buscas en el post una clave `id`, pero la misma no existe. Cuando envías un formulario, el post recibe los valores de los elementos asociándolos mediante la etiqueta `name` de cada elemento del form, eso significa que tu `form` debería tener un `input` u otro elemento válido cuyo `name="id"`. Si el id viene del `select` debes ponerlo así: `<select name="id">` de ese modo `$_POST` si tendría una clave `id` y un valor asociado.

Comment: siii muchas gracias a los dos, no me habia dado cuenta de que me falto ponerle el name al select, era algo tan simple como eso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando se envían datos de un formulario por POST o por GET, los campos de ese formulario son serializados, creando un array cuyas claves son las etiquetas `name` de los elementos del formulario y los valores son los `value`  (en el caso de los `input`), el `option` seleccionado en el caso de un `select`, etc.

En tu código, estás buscando dentro del POST un valor con clave `id` en esta línea:

```
$juego = $_POST['id'];
```

Pero si revisamos en tu formulario, no hay ningún campo que tenga un `name="id"`, razón por la cual estás teniendo el *`Undefined index: id`*

Para obtener el `id`, el cual según tu código HTML debería obtenerse del `select`, basta con que le pongas ese `name` a tu `select` del siguiente modo:

```
<select name="id">
        <?php

        while ($v = mysqli_fetch_array($t)) {
            echo "<option value=".$v['id'].">".$v['version_mk']."   </option>";

        };
        ?>
</select><br>
```

Haciendo eso, cuando el formulario sea serializado para enviarse, creará una clave `id`, cuyo valor será el `value` del `option` que se encuentre seleccionado en ese momento.